# Spring boot Swagger implementation using Spring Fox Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0

I am using the Springfox jars for implementation of swagger in my spring boot project the gradle dependencies look like:

```
dependencies {
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-webflux', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-configuration-processor', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
testCompile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-jpa', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-rest', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE'
implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
runtimeOnly 'org.hsqldb:hsqldb'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'io.projectreactor:reactor-test'
compile group: 'org.postgresql', name: 'postgresql', version: '42.2.5'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
testImplementation 'org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3'
compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger2', version: '2.9.1'
    compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-swagger-ui', version: '2.9.1'
    //compile group: 'io.springfox', name: 'springfox-data-rest', version: '2.9.1'
    // Unit testing dependencies
    // Set this dependency if you want to use Hamcrest matching

}
```

The Swagger config file:

```
package com.myapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.ApiInfoBuilder;
import springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;

@EnableSwagger2
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2).select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.mypackage.rtp.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*")).build().apiInfo(apiEndPointsInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiEndPointsInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Spring Boot REST API").description("Employee Management REST API")
                .license("Apache 2.0").licenseUrl("http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0.html").version("1.0.0")
                .build();
    }

}
```

While i do a spring bootRun i am getting the below warning:

```
WARN  [main] org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.getPluginFor(Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/Plugin;
```

and the server exits with :

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the following location:

    org.springframework.data.rest.core.support.UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.<init>(UnwrappingRepositoryInvokerFactory.java:57)

The following method did not exist:

    org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry.of(Ljava/util/List;)Lorg/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry;

The method's class, org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry, is available from the following locations:

    jar:file:/C:/Users/vgoswami/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/f380e7760032e7d929184f8ad8a33716b75c0657/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar!/org/springframework/plugin/core/PluginRegistry.class

It was loaded from the following location:

    file:/C:/Users/vgoswami/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.springframework.plugin/spring-plugin-core/1.2.0.RELEASE/f380e7760032e7d929184f8ad8a33716b75c0657/spring-plugin-core-1.2.0.RELEASE.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.springframework.plugin.core.PluginRegistry
```

Any help on the same would be highly appreciated...

Comment: Getting the same issue with Java 8, SpringBoot 2 and SpringFox 3 using springfox-boot-starter

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and after long time messing around with **spring-core**, **swagger etc** i found that below dependency was actual culprit

```
spring-boot-starter-data-rest
```

Just remove this and you are done.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution! I migrated an application from Spring Boot 1.X to 2.X and I solved this problem only removing `spring-boot-starter-data-rest` dependency.

Comment: But what if need actuator api? Removing this doesn't help

Comment: @vaibhav can you please accept the answer? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
springfox:
  documentation:
    auto-startup: false
```

mine work well~~

see https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/#configuring-startup

Answer (score -3):

Add swagger dependency with version 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>jcenter-snapshots</id>
    <name>jcenter</name>
    <url>http://oss.jfrog.org/artifactory/oss-snapshot-local/</url>
  </repository>
</repositories>
...
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-data-rest</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Use `@EnableSwagger2WebMvc` instead `@EnableSwagger2` and `@Import({SpringDataRestConfiguration.class})` annotations to enable swagger.

Documentation: https://springfox.github.io/springfox/docs/snapshot/

Answer (score -5):

Add this dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-plugin-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```